Midpoint of tangents From parabola to a line
Consider the parabola $C : (y ^ 2) = 4x$ and the straight line $L: y = x + 2$ Let $P$ be a variable point on $L$. Draw the two tangents from $P$ to $C$ and let $Q_{1}$ and $Q_{2}$ denote the two points of contact on $C$. Let $Q$ be the mid-point of the line segment joining $Q_{1}$ and $Q_{2}$ Find the locus of $Q$ as $P$ moves along $L$.
This question is from ISI B Stat 2022 sample paper
I tried finding the slope of tangent by differentiate the equation of parabola but was not able to solve it for the line and parabola
$$2Y*Y'=4$$
$$Y'=\frac{2}{Y}$$
Tangent will be
$$T : YY_0=2X + \frac{Y_0^2}{2}$$
Now I feel we should find the interview section between line L and T but there are too many variables so I am not able to find the the point of intersection.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

I have tried and given my idea on the problem not sure if it is sufficient

Take the general parabola $y^2=4ax$ in its parametric form:
$x=at^2\; y=2at$ where $t$ is the parameter
Now we know that the tangents to the parabola on points $Q_1(t_1)$ and $Q_2(t_2)$ intersect at $A(at_1t_2\ ,a(t_1+t_2))$ So the point $(A)$ must lie on the line $y=x+2\qquad\dots (A)$
$\implies a(t_1+t_2)=at_1t_2+2$
Let the middle point of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ be $Q(h,k)$.
$$h=\frac{a(t_1^2+t_2^2)}2 \; k=a(t_1+t_2)=at_1t_2+2\implies at_1t_2=k-2$$
$$h=\frac 1{2a}\left[(a(t_1+t_2))^2-2a^2t_1t_2\right]=\frac 1{2a}[k^2-2a(k-2)]$$
Substitute $h\rightarrow x\; k\rightarrow y$
So, Locus of $Q$ is:
$$x=\frac 1{2a}(y^2-2ay+4a)$$
In your very case $a=1$:
So, Here's the answer:
$$x=\frac 12(y^2-2y+4)\implies (y-1)^2=2x-3$$
Which is also a PARABOLA
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION
$1)$ Proof of statement $(A)$
equation of tangent at point $(t_1):\; t_1y=x+at_1^2\quad(1)$
and at $(t_2):\; t_2y=x+at_2^2\quad(2)$
Solving the Equations:
$$
(1)-(2)\\
y(t_1-t_2)=a(t_1-t_2)(t_1+t_2)\implies y=a(t_1+t_2)$$
Put y in (1):
$x=at_1t_2$

How can you tell the point of intersection is $$ A(t_1t_2,t_1+t_2)$$

@SaiPrabhav I just remember it as a result but it is quite easy to proof do you want me to include it in the solution? You can yourself easily derive it too just write the equation of tangent and solve it try it for yourself

If you can please. But thanks for the answer anyways

@saiprabhav i guess its fine now?

yes, thankyou now I get it

It is a standart exercise to find the tangent line of a parabola at a given point of it. The tangent line of $y^2=4x$ at $Q(u,v)$ is $y=\frac2v x+\frac v2.$
If this tangent line is intersecting the line $y=x+2$ at $P(a,a+2)$, then $v=a+2\pm\sqrt{a^2+4}.$ Therefore, we have two solutions for $Q$: $\small Q_{\pm}(\frac14(a+2\pm\sqrt{a^2+4})^2,a+2\pm\sqrt{a^2+4}).$
The middle point is then $Q=\frac{Q_++Q_-}2=(\frac12a^2+a+2,a+2).$ So, the locus of $Q$ is
$$x=\frac12(y-2)^2+y-2+2=\frac12y^2-y+2.$$
